# How to send a message to users who flagged a taxonomy term?

Tags: rules, flags, privatemsg

I want to send a message to users who have flagged, for example, the *Toys* taxonomy term. But only when a new node is created and contains the taxonomy term of Toys.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the Rules module yet?

Comment: yes, but can't figure out how to set it up.

Comment: Are you still thinking (wondering) about to do this with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module? Or is it only a matter of finding the time to ever "publish" your own answer using this module? Or would you rather want somebody else to add such answer? BTW: "merci" for your "support" that I seem to notice in the background of your profile picture ... which seems to be related to the "land-that-Drupal-(and-Dries)-originate-from"!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I got lazy in posting the answer since it was my own question, but if you would like to post the answer, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create this using a Custom PHP code in Rules and execute the following conditional code on 'After saving new content of type...' event trigger :

```
if( count(taxonomy_get_term_by_name('[node:field-tags]')) ) return TRUE; 
else return FALSE;
```

Then create an 'action to send an email'.

Requires 
-PHP Filter,
-Rules. 

-Here the content type assumes the default 'Article' with default Tags field 'field_tags'

```
{ "rules_tst" : {
"LABEL" : "Test Rule",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
"IF" : [
  { "php_eval" : { "code" : "if( count(taxonomy_get_term_by_name(\u0027[node:field-tags]\u0027)) ) return TRUE; \r\nelse return FALSE;  " } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : "me@mine.com",
      "subject" : "test subject Toys confirmed!",
      "message" : "There are toys to play with!",
      "language" : [ "" ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

I ahve included an importable for you to test.

Comment: oh, I found the solution to this using rules without any custom php. Thanks for taking the time to come up with a possible solution. Eventhough, I didn't get the chance to test your answer, I'll accept your answer as a token of gratitude